# What is the difference between prototypal and concatenative inheritance in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, inheritance

Could someone explain me the difference between prototypal and concatenative inheritance in JavaScript?
I know that they are related to each other and I feel like I understand both of those terms, but I can't really contrast them.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: never heard "concatenative inheritance". What is that?

Comment: @JonasWilms neither had I. https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-heart-soul-of-prototypal-oo-concatenative-inheritance-a3b64cb27819